# How to find the Struts version being used in a project

Tags: struts

How to find the **Struts version being used** in a **Web Application project** in Eclipse?

My **struts-config.xml** says

```
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts 
Configuration 1.2//EN"

"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_2.dtd">
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Open struts jar and read version in MANIFEST file, inside META-INF folder.

Comment: Unable to find taglib [bean] for URI: [/tags/struts-bean].. i have checked everything but still im getting this error.Please help me resolve this

Answer (score 11):

We can find out the struts version by observing the doctype of the Struts-config file. 
For Example if your struts config file contains the below DTD then we can say that it is Struts 1.1 version.

```
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC 
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.1//EN" 
"http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/**struts-config_1_1.dtd**">
```

Answer (score 5):

On a Windows system:

1. Open file explorer, search for **struts*.jar**
2. Open **struts-core.jar** with a unzip tool (e.g. IZArc2Go)
3. Open **META-INF folder** and open **MANIFEST.MF** file with a text editor
4. There you will find **Specification-Version:** with the version number

Some additional release info:

- [Latest Struts 2 version](http://struts.apache.org/download.cgi) is 2.5.2
- [Struts 1 is EOL](http://struts.apache.org/struts1eol-announcement.html) with version 1.3.10 in December 2008

Answer (score 4):

and the property to look at in manifest.mf is 'Specification-Version'

Answer (score 3):

Dont refer to the Manifest-version. instead you refer to the "Specification-Version"

Eg:
Specification-Version: 1.2.4

That means the struts verison is 1.2.4